# In R, weighted average of one column among all dataframes in a list

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a list of dataframes. Each dataframe contains the same column (Gender, Age, salary) but different rows (You can think of it as a list of experiment results with different participants in each experiment).The sizes of the dataframes are the same (100 by 9). Now I have a weight vector whose length is the same as that of the dataframe list. I want to produce another dataframe which displays the weighted average of salary and age among those dataframes. For example, the weighted average of salary = (weight 1 * salary column in dataframe 1 + weight 2 * salary column in dataframe 2 + ...) / (weight 1 + weight 2 + ...). The end result for this is a vector with the same size as the salary column.

Can anyone advise me on how to achieve this? Thank you so much!

I tried different ways but nothing worked.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. What exactly did you try? And in what ways did they not work?

Answer (score 0):

(1) For each data frame in a list, calculate column means for "salary" and "age". (2) Weight those means by a data frame specific weight (scalar). (3) Report results. One of many ways to achieve this:

Toy data:

```
set.seed(1)
# generate some purely random values 
ls_df <- list(df1 = data.frame(salary = rnorm(10L, 2000L, 700L), 
                               age = rnorm(10L, 41L, 6L)), 
              df2 = data.frame(salary = rnorm(10L, 3000L, 800L),
                               age = rnorm(10L, 52L, 4L)))
w <- c(.6, .4)
```

> I want to produce another dataframe which displays the weighted average of salary and age among those dataframes.

```
df_out <- 
  lapply(X = ls_df, 
         FUN = \(x) colMeans(x = x[, c("salary", "age")], na.rm = TRUE)) |>
  list2DF() |>
  `rownames<-`(c("salary", "age")) |>
  sweep(MARGIN = 2L, STATS = w, FUN = "*") |> # w / sum(w)
  round(digits = 2L)
```

this gives:

```
> df_out
           df1     df2
salary 1255.53 1157.22
age      25.50   20.99
```

If you want to multiply by w_1 / (w_1 + w_2) instead, then replace `w`  with `w / sum(w)` inside of `sweep()`. Obviously, for 0.6 + 0.4 = 1 nothing changes.

If you like your result to be a numeric vector for each variable, simply type `salaray <- as.numeric(df_out[1L, ])`, and `age <- as.numeric(df_out[2L, ])`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. But I don't want age to be weight. So just to build upon your response, We have salary and age columns for both dataframes. And we have a single weight for the first dataframe (say 0.6), another weight for the second dataframe (say 0.4). The weights are stored by a vector w <- c(0.6, 0.4). And I want to take the weight average of salary in the first and second dataframe. And the result will be a vector and we store that in another dataframe. And we do this for age as well. The end result will be another dataframe containing salary and age. Hope it clarifies.

Comment: See my recent update.